# Why the AST created by Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser for this query contains SqlTableValuedFunctionRefExpression?

Tags: sql-server, parsing

Please, observe the following simple query:

```
SELECT ShortName FROM Groups (nolock)
```

I parse it like this:

```
var parseResult = Parser.Parse("SELECT ShortName FROM Groups (nolock)");
Dump(parseResult.Script);

...

private static void Dump(string indent, SqlCodeObject sqlCodeObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine(indent + sqlCodeObject.GetType().Name);
    indent += "  ";
    foreach (var child in sqlCodeObject.Children)
    {
        Dump(indent, child);
    }
}
```

This outputs the following AST:

```
SqlScript
  SqlBatch
    SqlSelectStatement
      SqlSelectSpecification
        SqlQuerySpecification
          SqlSelectClause
            SqlSelectScalarExpression
              SqlColumnRefExpression
                OnePartObjectIdentifier
                  SqlIdentifier
          SqlFromClause
            SqlTableValuedFunctionRefExpression
              OnePartObjectIdentifier
                SqlIdentifier
              SqlColumnRefExpression
                OnePartObjectIdentifier
                  SqlIdentifier
```

My question - why is `SqlFromClause` parent to `SqlTableValuedFunctionRefExpression`? I do not have any function calls in the query.

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you specify the `WITH` keyword before the hint (i.e.. `SELECT ShortName FROM Groups WITH (nolock)`). Note omitting `WITH` is deprecated. FWIW, It works fine for me with or without `WITH` using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom` parser.

Comment: It is exactly the answer. Without `with` the parser thinks a function is called. I first used `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom`, but - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185651/is-it-possible-to-instruct-visual-studio-not-to-print-first-chance-exceptions-wh Using the ScriptDom parser prevents me from debugging the code without losing my sanity. I had to switch. Please, arrange your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DanGuzman - would you happen to know how to instruct the parser to respect the deprecated syntax, the one where `with` is optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only combination of settings I could get the desired result from using SMO 150.18208.0:

```
var opts = new ParseOptions("GO", true, DatabaseCompatibilityLevel.Version80);
opts.TransactSqlVersion = TransactSqlVersion.Version105;

var parseResult = Parser.Parse("SELECT ShortName FROM Groups (nolock)", opts);
Dump("  ",parseResult.Script);
```

outputs

```
SqlScript
    SqlBatch
      SqlSelectStatement
        SqlSelectSpecification
          SqlQuerySpecification
            SqlSelectClause
              SqlSelectScalarExpression
                SqlColumnRefExpression
                  OnePartObjectIdentifier
                    SqlIdentifier
            SqlFromClause
              SqlTableRefExpression
                OnePartObjectIdentifier
                  SqlIdentifier
                SqlTableHint
```